# Rails 4: Want to check if an object already exists when submitting a form and then update that record with additional info (many-to-many relationship)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, has-many-through

I'm building an online personal library application and I want to have it so that users can add books to their library. I want to check and see if the book being added to a library already exists within the database and then add that instance of the book into that library. Right now, my form is set up to always create new instances of a book and does not check if that book exists. I'm still fairly new at Rails and I'd appreciate any help. Here's my code:

**Model**

library.rb:

```
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :shelves, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :catalogs, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :books, :through => :catalogs, dependent: :destroy

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }
  ...
end
```

book.rb:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :catalogs, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :libraries, :through => :catalogs, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :bookshelves, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :shelves, :through => :bookshelves, dependent: :destroy

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :author, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :publisher, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :isbn, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  ...
end
```

catalog.rb:

```
class Catalog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :library
end
```

**Controller**

books_controller.rb

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)
    @library = current_user.library

    if @book.save
      @book.catalogs.create(:library_id => @library.id)
      flash[:success] = "Book added to library!"
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      render 'current_user'
    end
  end

  ...

private
  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:title, :author, :publisher, :isbn, shelf_ids: [])
  end
  ...
end
```

**View**

_book_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@book) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Book Title" %>
    <%= f.text_field :author, placeholder: "Author" %>
    <%= f.text_field :publisher, placeholder: "Publisher" %>
    <%= f.text_field :isbn, placeholder: "ISBN" %>

    <%= f.fields_for :catalogs do |ff| %>
      <%= ff.hidden_field :library_id %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.collection_select :shelf_ids, current_user.library.shelves.all, :id, :name, {:selected => @book.shelf_ids, :include_blank => true}, {:multiple => true} %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Add Book to Library", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How do you plan to determine whether the book is a duplicate?

Comment: Do you mean if it's a duplicate within the database or within a particular library?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good fit for [`find_or_initialize_by`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_initialize_by).

In that case you would do this in your model. So if it finds one that exists it will return that instance, if not it will return a new instance (in your controller):

**Edit**, you may need to manually pass in just your `book` parameters (to avoid the other params from your form). Also **edited** to reflect shelfs.

```
 @book = Book.find_or_initialize_by(name: params[:name], author:  params[:author], publisher: params[:publisher], isbn: params[:isbn]])
 shelfs = Shelf.find(params[:shelf_ids]) 
 @book.shelfs = shelfs
 @book.save
```

When it comes to the `shelfs`, there are probably many other approaches that can work, but this will find all instances of them based on the params and then just assign those to this `book` instance.

Comment: I forgot to put my validations in the original post, so that's fixed. I tried this and I get an error telling me that column books.shelf_ids does not exist. shelf_ids exists in the Bookshelf table, which is a join table between Book and another model called Shelf.

Comment: It looks like that value is coming from the form fields (that aren't listed in the params).

Comment: Sorry, I had copied over some old code for the books controller. Everything should be updated now.

Comment: See my edit (with passing in only the fields relevant to the book), this way your only calling it with the fields that could be duplicated in the model that you want to find based on. You could also just call one of those fields if you wanted.

Comment: The problem with that is I need to pass the shelf_ids array as well. That's how I'm able to tell which shelf a book exists in within a library. Is there a way to pass that array after `find_or_initialize_by`?

Comment: I updated to do a find based on the `shelfs` params. If I'm understanding how you want this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way of doing this is to use a rails validation on your  Book model.  For example you can add `validates :title, uniqueness: true` to your Book model to check if the title is unique before submitting the form.  There's a list of validations [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

If you still want to validate the record in the controller you can check for a new record with @book.new_record? or see if the record exists with @book.persisted? like this:

```
if @book.new_record?
  // do something with new record
else
  redirect_to some path
end
```

But, it seems like you just want to check if it's unique or not and a validation might be easier.